# library missing dependency appcompat

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

I'm writing a library(module) in android studio 3.0 with gradle 4.1 minsdk version is 21 target is 26. My problem is that my module(.jar file) doesn't contain appcomat dependency (I opened the jar file it isnt there I also tried retrofit2 same result). I've tried with implementation and with compile. I'm building a Unity plugin btw. The module works fine if I call basic methods (return a number, screen density etc).
build.gradle file, I didn't modify anything except adding appcompat

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26



defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

The error I get from logcat -s Unity:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" 
on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mycompanyname.howto-2/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycompanyname.howto-2/lib/arm,
/data/app/com.mycompanyname.howto-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and then [edit] your question.**

Comment: Sorry I copy pasted the error that Ive got from unity and the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

DELETE THAT FOLDER > .gradle.
after re gradle download file